# How to whitelist specific email domains during registration based on user role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-validation

I have a WordPress site that allows a user to sign up as an employer or candidate during registration. The candidates will be college students so I would like to add some functionality to validate whether they are using an *@school.edu* email domain. During the registration process the user is asked whether they are looking "to hire" or "for a job" which determines what role they are assigned. Candidates should be validated for .edu emails only.

I am using a custom theme that uses their own registration process combined with WooCommerce. I have contacted both the theme developer and WooCommerce support to inquire how I can accomplish this, but they only pointed me to the section of the code that I would need to customize. I don't know **PHP** and I cannot afford to hire a developer since I am not currently seeking revenue on my website (proof-of-concept). I know this is only a few lines of code and was looking for someone to help me accomplish this OR at the very least point me in the right direction.

I managed to find some solutions on email validation on SO, but they aren't based on user role. I like the idea of using an Array so that I can slowly add more colleges/universities as I grow my user base (currently beta testing in one school). Something like:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$allowed = array('school.edu');

// Make sure the address is valid
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
$explodedEmail = explode('@', $email);
$domain = array_pop($explodedEmail);

if ( ! in_array($domain, $allowed))
{
// Not allowed
}

}
```

Here is the email validation section of the code in question that I need to modify (don't worry I'll attach the entire code as well):

```
 if(!is_email($user_email)) {
 //invalid email
 workscout_form_errors()->add('email_invalid', __('Invalid email','workscout'));}
```

I would also like to include a simple validation error, when a student enters a non-.edu email address. Any help, without someone lecturing me to "learn PHP on your own" or complaining about the formatting and structure of my question, would be greatly appreciated.

LINK TO FULL REGISTRATION CODE: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eatPr8F-y1c-0sG2Xnepf3Dw6Mj2Of6I/view?usp=sharing

CANDIDATE ROLE SELECTION: `LINE 213`

EMAIL VALIDATION: `LINE 398`

**EDIT:** *I appreciate all answers in advanced, but I will need to know how to implement any answer into the current registration.php file my theme uses without breaking anything (currently using a child theme to help prevent this). Meaning I need to know what line to insert the answer into and any answer also needs to use the functions that are called in the registration.php file. I am a complete novice with PHP and would just like to "plug-and-play" without the guilt I currently feel for even asking for help and not being able to do this on my own.*

**EDIT 2:** *If I had to take a total stab in the dark based on my nonexistent knowledge of PHP and basic understanding of coding logic, I would guess that it would be something like this:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
function strposa($haystack, $needles=array(), $offset=0) {
    $chr = array();
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
            $res = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
            if ($res !== false) $chr[$needle] = $res;
    }
    if(empty($chr)) return false;
    return min($chr);
}
```

> Just put allowed domain into array if you want to match multiple domains

```
$allowed_candidate_domain = array("school.edu","work.edu","otherdomain.edu"); //OR ["school.edu",...];
if (strposa(strtolower($user_email), $allowed_candidate_domain, 1)){
echo "domain allowed";
} else {
echo "domain disallowed";
}
```

> If you only want to matching one domain only use this:

```
if (strpos(strtolower($user_email), "school.edu") === false){
// Email domain disallowed === FALSE
}
```

> You can use preg_match too

```
if (!preg_match('(school.edu)', strtolower($user_email))){
// invalid/disallowed Candidate email
} else {
// Valid candidate email
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I need to be able to insert any answer directly into the registration.php (linked above) file without having to figure out where to put it and what functions I need to insert into the '//Do stuff if' sections. I have a small baby infant brain when it comes to learning PHP, I just go cross-eyed and poop myself.

Comment: Please see my second **EDIT** above. @DimasLanjaka

Comment: Wrong array sir. use array("school.edu"); . Then on if (strpos($allowed_domain, $_POST["confirm_email"]) === false){ /* do stuff if false */ }

Comment: Remove $user_role = 'candidate'

Comment: There === FALSE for actually false then !== FALSE for true if you put !== TRUE replace with === FALSE for verifying if that actually false

Comment: $allowed_candidate_domain just put ARRAY. Like ["school.edu","domain.edu"] OR array("school.edu","domain.edu") ITS Same function of array :)

Comment: Sorry before i forgotten if strpos must be turn into function then can be putted on array

Comment: Will this validate the email address based on the user role ex: when the user selects "for a job" from the drop-down in the registration form?

Comment: Yes. You must put it on first validation. Or wrap it. $user_email = where user inputed email eg: <input name="workscout_user_email" ...>